# SQL Server 2008 view returns nothing when one table is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have view of two tables that appears to be returning absolutely nothing rather than 0 records. In SQL Server Management Studio, if I execute it, it does not return zero records like an empty table would, the results pane is just blank.

One table in the view is empty, one isn't and it's using an inner join.

On the server side I cannot handle it as an empty recordset like I can with an empty table, the recordset object is null.

Both tables have primary keys which are both identities.

It's likely that I have not seen this behaviour before because I would usually make views from tables with records in, and they would remain populated after that point.

Why would a view return null, when a table returns 0 records?

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb2d3/2) - appears to return 0 records here, rather than nothing, but this is the same SQL that is returning nothing inside SQLSMS

[screenshot of SQLSMS running this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxWCn.jpg) - Usually I get 0 records and a row of nulls, here I get nothing, it has completed and is not hanging.

The asp page gets NULL back as a result of trying to open the recordset.

Thanks

Comment: To help us help you, please create an SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com of your tables and view. (Please disregard my first attempt at this comment).

Comment: To help us help you, please create an <a href="http://sqlfiddle.com">SQLFidle</a> of your tables and view.

Comment: In the fiddle, there does not seem to be any data in the cv table. Is that intentional?

Comment: A SQL query cannot return `null`. There is something wrong with your client-side code. Please post it. Also, a view always returns a result set. Maybe you are invoking a function or procedure?

Comment: *Is* it returning nothing, or is it in fact hanging and never returning at all? Might some other piece of code have an exclusive lock on one of these tables?

Comment: Well, your screenshot is showing column names, so that is *not* a null response, it's an empty recordset.

Comment: Rikalous, Thanks, when I return a recordset from say, just one of the tables, I get a different response, and a different result server side. I see a row of null values in SQLSMSM, and server side I get a recordset with a count of zero.